# Django Restful Model Foreign Key - Specify From and To Field

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django and trying to understand how to setup database relationships in the models. I have the following two models:

```
class BusinessTypes(models.Model):
    categoryID = models.AutoField(db_column='TypeID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    category = models.CharField(db_column='type', max_length=200)
    newtype = models.CharField(db_column='newType', max_length=200)  # Field name made lowercase.
    dec = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tabsize = models.CharField(db_column='tabSize', max_length=10)  # Field name made lowercase.
    #subcategory = models.ForeignKey(BusinessTypesSub, to_field='Type_ID')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'business_types'
        app_label = 'sapi'

class BusinessTypesSub(models.Model):
    subcategoryID = models.AutoField(db_column='Type_subID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    categoryID = models.IntegerField(db_column='Type_ID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    status = models.IntegerField()
    showpub = models.IntegerField(db_column='showPub')  # Field name made lowercase.
    showcity = models.CharField(db_column='showCity', max_length=20)  # Field name made lowercase.
    subcategory = models.CharField(db_column='sub', max_length=255)
    sub_alternative = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(BusinessTypes,from_field='Type_ID', to_field='TypeID')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'business_types_sub'
        app_label = 'api'
```

There is a one-to-many relationship between the business_types and business_types_sub tables. I would like to setup a foreign key relationship so that if I create a view which calls a serializer over BusinessTypesSub I can access the value of the category field in the BusinessTypesModel. The foreign key relationship should be from the BusinessTypesSub field 'Type_ID' to the BusinessTypes field 'TypeID'.

How can I create this? I've tried add the following to the BusinessTypesSub model but it just creates the following error:

```
category = models.ForeignKey(BusinessTypes,to_field='TypeID')

BusinessTypes has no field named 'TypeID'
```

Also, how can I call this in a view/serializer. For example how would I add the 'category' to the following serializer:

```
class BusinessTypesSubSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.RelatedField(source='BusinessType', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = BusinessTypesSub
        fields = ('categoryID', 'category', 'subcategoryID', 'subcategory')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have specified the wrong to_field, it should be name of the categoryID field of BusinessType class, not the name of the column in the database:

```
category = models.ForeignKey(BusinessTypes, to_field='categoryID')
```

To display category in your BusinessTypesSubSerializer, you can choose from several options defined here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/. E.g. for StringRelatedField, you would define:

```
class BusinessTypesSubSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = BusinessTypesSub
        fields = ('categoryID', 'category', 'subcategoryID', 'subcategory')
```

Comment: When I try to add the Foreign Key constraint to the BusinessTypesSub I get the following error message: Unknown column 'business_types_sub.category_id' in 'field list